# How to synchronize multiple React lucky draw web-app at the same time?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, socket.io, axios

Christmas is coming and I am writing a website for lucky draw, but this one will be a bit different since due to covid, we are not suggested to gather in the same place. So, even by zoom or skype, what I want to do is I want to host the website on 1 computer and then share the link to my family and thus they can join the lucky draw by accessing the same link. When I click the "Draw" button on my computer, I hope others can see what I drew as well on their screen. But I am new to `React`, any library can help me do a `live-chat` like thing? I have a prototype for lucky draw already. I am glad to share the website to everyone once I finished it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I would like to update the website at the same time when someone click the button.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a solution like Socket.io. It's a library that's available in many languages (a.o. JavaScript for React and Python). You've tagged this question with Python so a solution could be Socket.io with Flask (https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You don't need React to work (if you really want to, there are many tutorials available online), so I'll provide an example in Python and HTML:

Folder structure:

```
myproject/
  main.py
  index_participants.html
  index_host.html
```

main.py

```py
# Make sure to install flask-socketio: pip install flask-socketio

import random

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret!"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


# Create a route for the participants (http://localhost:5000/)
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return send_from_directory(".", "index_participants.html")


# Create a route for the host (http://localhost:5000/host)
@app.route("/host")
def host():
    return send_from_directory(".", "index_host.html")


# Handle an event (host clicks a button)
@socketio.on("host_clicks_button")
def handle_host_clicks_button():

    # For demo purposes, just draw a random number
    some_random_number = random.randint(1, 10)

    # Send the random number to all connected clients (including the host)
    emit("random_number_picked", some_random_number, broadcast=True)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, debug=True)
```

index_participants.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>For participants</h1>
        <p>The random number is: <span id="random-number">...</span></p>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Connect to the server
            var socket = io();

            // Listen for events
            socket.on('random_number_picked', function(newNumber) {

                // Update a part of the page
                document.getElementById("random-number").innerHTML = newNumber;
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index_host.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>For participants</h1>
        <p>The random number is: <span id="random-number">...</span></p>
        <h1>For the host</h1>
        <button id="host-button">Draw new random number</button>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Connect to the server
            var socket = io();

            // Listen for events
            socket.on('random_number_picked', function(newNumber) {

                // Update a part of the page
                document.getElementById("random-number").innerHTML = newNumber;
            });

            // Listen to click events on the button
            document.getElementById("host-button").addEventListener("click", function() {

                // When the button is clicked, send a message to the server
                socket.emit("host_clicks_button");
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Run the Python file (`python main.py`) and open 2 browsers. Navigate to the participants view from one browser window (http://localhost:5000) and the host view on the other (http://localhost:5000/host). Click the button as host and the clients should get updated.

Serving this to the outside world can be a little more tricky, but you can try services like https://ngrok.com/ which basically publish a port on your machine to the outside world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It definitely gives me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a server to connect different React web-apps.

The server will proxy messages between the apps and will allow joining a private room/chat by unique ID.

You can run it locally and share your server with your family with https://ngrok.com/ as Gijs Wobben suggested or use a hosting provider to share it with the world.

[Socket.io](https://socket.io) library would be the best solution for real-time messaging as Gijs Wobben suggests.

I've found this amazing [Real-Time Chat App](https://hackernoon.com/creating-real-time-chat-app-using-react-and-socketio-with-e2e-encryption-b0113u5s) created by [Rishabh Verma](https://github.com/RishabhVerma098).

I think it matches your requirements well and would be a good example for you:

- [Client-side](https://github.com/RishabhVerma098/chatapp) is created with React
- [Server-side](https://github.com/RishabhVerma098/chatappBackend) is NodeJS
- It supports private rooms
- It has end-to-end encryption
- It uses Socket.io for communications and it's well-integrated into client-side using Redux
- It's already [hosted](https://chatrishabh.surge.sh/)
- There is [the article](https://hackernoon.com/creating-real-time-chat-app-using-react-and-socketio-with-e2e-encryption-b0113u5s) explaining how it works